# Cocoapods build phase errors

Tags: objective-c, xcode, shell, cocoapods

When creating a new Xcode-project using Cocoapods and creating the xcworkspace-file using "pod install", Cocoapods all adds some build phases, including a script to check the manifest.lock.

When building my app, that build phase fails to build.
I get the error:

```
line 2: diff: command not found
line 4: cat: command not found
```

Also when executing the Pods-resources.sh -script, my build fails on executing the "rsync"-command, saying he cannot find that command.

Any suggestions on how to make this work?
my $PATH-variable clearly states all /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin statements.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

if you had already tried "pod install" and which returned error about ".cocoapods/repos (Errno::ENOENT)", you might need to do "pod setup" first and then "pod install" again.